# Get Formula value instead of formula code .net c# Crystal Reports SDK

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects, crystal-reports-viewer

I am very close to solving the elusive single-pass bursting and need some help.
I have a button that exports a new .rpt with saved data and my idea was to then query this saved data report and GET the necessary info.
I can access a formula but it returns the actual CR syntax and not the printed value.
How can I get the actual value?

Also if anyone knows how to get the group header #1 value that would also be great.

Thanks

Issue with:

```
formulaField.Text
```

```
public void btnExportToPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(destinationFolderFinal))
{
ReportDocument savedReport = new ReportDocument();
savedReport.Load(destinationFolderFinal);
viewer.ReportSource = savedReport;
viewer.Refresh();
Section groupHeaderSection = savedReport.ReportDefinition.Sections["GroupHeaderSection1"];
FormulaFieldDefinition formulaField = savedReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["BURST"];
string formulaValue = formulaField.Text;
string sanitizedFormulaValue = SanitizeFilename(formulaValue.ToString());
string pdfFileName = sanitizedFormulaValue + ".pdf";
string pdfFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, pdfFileName);
savedReport.ExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
savedReport.ExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
DiskFileDestinationOptions diskOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions
{
DiskFileName = pdfFilePath
};

savedReport.ExportOptions.DestinationOptions = diskOptions;
savedReport.Export();

MessageBox.Show("Report exported to PDF.");
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("Please select a destination folder first.");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I handled the Crystal Report PDF bursting in a different way:

1. Add "Burst to PDF" button to export report to temp pdf and add bookmark tree based on report groups.
2. Then split/burst this temp pdf based on the second level bookmarks.
3. Delete temp pdf.

In my testing I managed to split 1000 PDFs with random page numbering in 30 seconds.